# Not Response contant logged with Spring CommonsRequestLoggingFilter

Tags: java, spring, rest, logging

My issue is that I can have a log of the Web Service Response with Spring CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.

Here is some details:

I expose a REST Service like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "dessins/{concatDesignNumber}/fichiers", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity findFilesListByConcatDesignNumber(
            @PathVariable("concatDesignNumber") String concatDesignNumber, Pageable pageable) {

    ...

    return ResponseEntity.ok(collectorResult);
}
```

I want to log the request and the response, including the repsonse content.

Currently, I use CommonsRequestLoggingFilter like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        // truncate payloads
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(100000000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("Request received: ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

It works well with the request, but the response is not logged. Is there a clean way to log the response, response content and response error ?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Regards,
Florian